# Install on Dell E6430 hangs

Tags: kubuntu, dell

I'm trying to install kubuntu 14.04 on a Dell latitude E6430. I've tried both install from usb and from dvd.

The different attempts result in a little different behaviour, but most of the time, I see a "keyboard = man in a circle" sign, and then the install hangs. Or I can choose 'start Kubuntu', then a lot of cpu power is used, but the install hangs.

Not sure if I can provide any more useful information to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm installing the 64-bit version.

Comment: Did you checked the md5sum of your iso https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM ?